AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'embed_documents'
I have uploaded PDF file and split file into chunks, then apply tokenizer to each chunck and created embeddings. But when i try to store my embedding in FIASS, it give me AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'embed_documents' error. My embeddings are in tensors. I also tried to converts it 2D Numpy array, but still problem sustained. Pl guide.
it give me AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'embed_documents' error
